# How to fix MySQL INSERT INTO (Syntax Error)?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

This is my code

```
USE `es_extended`;

INSERT INTO `users` (
  `license` varchar(50),
  `money` int(11),
  `bank` int(11),
  `permission_level` int(11)
);
```

And every time I try to import it to my database I got this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(50),
  `money` int(11),
  `bank` int(11),
  `permission_level` int(11)
)' at line 2
```

Comment: You are mixing elements of CREATE and INSERT

Comment: First thing you need to do before asking question here is read the basics of you want to use: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-statement.aspx

Comment: Probably reading a SQL book will be a good start.  Even I don't know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create your table:

```
Create table `users` ( `license` varchar(50), `money` int(11), `bank` int(11), `permission_level` int(11) );
```

To insert you could do:

```
Insert into  `users` ( `license`, `money`, `bank`, `permission_level`) values ('test', 123, 456, 789)
```